# Buffer overflow with disabled shell?

Tags: c, linux

AFAIK, a buffer overflow is achieved by overwriting memory adjacent to a C variable's buffer. This overwriting is used to spawn a shell which executes commands.

But what if the user that is running the program vulnerable to a buffer overflow has the shell disabled ?

/etc/passwd:

user1:x:1000:1000:user1,,,,:/home/user1:**/bin/false**

sudo -u user1 /usr/bin/programname

Comment: Buffer overflow may be used for spawning a shell, but it might be used for other things as well.

Comment: If the user/program is properly secured e.g. chroot, etc. you shouldnt worry about system-wide security.

Comment: can you explain what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: Please specify what you want answered and also what you are trying to achieve. This will make it easier for people to answer your question in a good way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Shell disabled" only matters **if you're actually logging in**. If you're exploiting an already running program then you don't need to log in.

Answer (score 0):

Exploits do not use a shell which is configured for a user — they normally include a binary code, [shellcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellcode), which are functionally equivalent to a primitive shell, meaning that it will start any chosen executable — for example a real shell program. Exploited program is then tricked to execute this code.

There are many different shellcodes available on the net, for example which do not include a byte '\0', so they will be passed unharmed as a C string, or which only include printable characters, valid unicode strings etc.